# 90-days without a visa in South Korea

Tags: visas, us-citizens, south-korea, visa-free-entry, repeat-visits

I am a frequent visitor to South Korea without a visa as a U.S. citizen. Each time I left Korea without fully staying those full 90 days but am wondering whether there is a limit to this count (one can stay up to addition of 90 days in a year for instance).

Just this year alone, I've visited three times already and plan to come back again in a few months.

Also, is it possible to "negotiate" a longer stay with the embassy at all?

Thank you.

Comment: The obvious questions are why do you need to visit South Korea so frequently and for such long periods (not the normal visitor pattern), and how do you support yourself while you’re there? Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110991/how-many-days-can-i-stay-in-korea-annually

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.

Comment: The answer is: "You can visit as much as they let you." and "No you can't negotiate".